# geolocation watchposition multiple locations?

Tags: javascript

I have this function where I watch my position and at the same time I want to display multiple locations comming from json array, but I need to watch them not only display them on the map. I got this so far:

```
function initMap(userId,locations) {
  var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  var directionsDisplay;
  var icn="img/mechanic.png";
  var meIcn="img/me.png";

  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
   polylineOptions: {
   strokeColor: "red"
  }
});

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
 zoom: 13,
 center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.529773,-113.509387), //ALBERTA
 mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

var marker, i;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

$.each(locations, function(index, element) {  
 watchMec = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position){
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(
             parseFloat(element.longitud), parseFloat(element.latitud)),
        map: map,
        icon: icn
    });  
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
              // My position
  watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position){
    lat = position.coords["latitude"];
lng = position.coords["longitude"];
markerMe = new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: lat, lng: lng},
    map:map, icon:meIcn});              
  });

  return function() {
    var distinationOrigin = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);  //My position
    var destinationMarker = parseFloat(element.longitud) + ',' + '' +
     parseFloat(element.latitud);
    infowindow.setContent(element.datos);
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
    calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay,
     distinationOrigin, destinationMarker, infowindow);
   }
  })(marker, i));
 })
}
```

In firebug (mozilla) I get a typeError but I don't know where exactly.

How can I use watchposition in this case?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "_I get a typeError but I don't know where exactly_". Firebug mentions the exact position in the error on the right (filename, row and column). Just click on it to jump to the place where the error occurred.

Comment: And it mentions the exact error message too, btw.

Comment: Yes, ok. The exact position of the error is here:

    ...turnValue="handled")};mb=function(a,b){a.__e3_||(a.__e3_
    {});a=a.__e3_;a[b]||(a[...

and the exact error message is this: TypeError: a is undefined

The file is in https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&key=xxx

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved, the problem was that I was putting the listener event out of the marker object, so the marker variable wasn't parsing correctly. The solution is this:

```
  $.each(locations, function(index, element) {  
watchMec = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position){
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: {lat:parseFloat(element.longitud), lng:parseFloat
             (element.latitud)},
        map: map,
        icon:icn
    }); 

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        // My position
        watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function(position){
            lat = position.coords["latitude"];
            lng = position.coords["longitude"];
            markerMe = new google.maps.Marker({position: {lat: lat, lng: lng}, map: map, icon:meIcn});              
        });

        return function() {
            var distinationOrigin = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);  // MI POSICION
            var destinationMarker = parseFloat(element.longitud) + ',' + '' + parseFloat(element.latitud);
            infowindow.setContent(element.datos);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
            calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay, distinationOrigin, destinationMarker, infowindow);
        }
    })(marker, i));      
});
});
```